# appending to a file in linux/unix instead of overwriting

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I am writing a script to write data into a file. The script is

```
for i in {1..10..2}
 do
   echo $i > tot.txt
 done
```

But everytime `tot.txt` gets overwritten. How can append without overwriting? Thanks

Comment: Use `printf '%s\n' {1..10..2} > tot.txt` instead.

Comment: @TomFenech If you're going to do that, why not just use `seq`?

Comment: What's so great about `seq`? It's a separate process, as opposed to a built-in operation and is completely nonstandard. If you're using bash (which presumably the OP is), then my suggestion is perfectly valid. It also comes with the added bonus that you can customise the format of each line :)

Comment: @Mr.Llama, ...in part because `seq` is a non-standard tool, not guaranteed to exist either as part of the POSIX spec or as a bash builtin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use redirect once after `done`:

```
for i in {1..10..2}
do
   echo $i
done > tot.txt

cat tot.txt
1
3
5
7
9
```

PS:  If you already have some content in `tot.txt` then you can use `>> tot.txt` after `done`.

Comment: Not to nitpick, but this answer isn't technically *appending* to the file.  It's merely capturing all the output of the `for .. done` block and overwriting `tot.txt` with it.

Comment: That's right but it does what OP is trying to achieve. If OP already has some content in `tot.txt` then OP can use `>> tot.txt` after `done`.

Comment: This works well, but I would like the output tab-separated like 1 3 5 7 etc. Can you suggest edits. Thanks

Comment: You can then use: `printf "%s\t" {1..10..2}`

Answer (score 3):

Use >> in place of > to append to the end of the file.

Comment: This works, but putting it inside a loop is very inefficient -- it reopens the file every time it wants to append another line to it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy- I agree with you,but,just gave a quick solution. anubhava has already given the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
   for i in {1..10..2}
   do
          echo $i >> tot.txt
   done
```

Comment: Needlessly inefficient, as it reopens the file once every iteration. Thus, this is significantly worse than the solution already given by anubhava.